# how to check if each letter in a password is part of a list of allowed characters

Tags: python

I am making a code where I want to check if the letters in a password are part of a list of allowed letters.
 here is the code I am using:

```
letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L''M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','!','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','-','_','=','+']
passlist = list(password)
print(passlist)
for i in range(len(passlist)):
    on = False
    print(passlist[i])
    for x in range(len(letters)):
        print(letters[x])
        a = passlist[i] + letters[x]
        print(a)
        if passlist[i] == letters[x]:
            on == True
    if on == False:
        print('password cannot contain the following character: ',passlist[i])
        go = True
        global go
        return None
```

if the letter is part of the allowed letter the result should be true.
however it always comes out as false.

Comment: This has already been asked numerous times. You can use `all(p in letters for p in password)`. No need for going imperative.

Comment: And if you want to get the list of outliers, you can take a symmetric set difference.

Comment: Just as a basic learning comment. The error in your code is on the line `on == True`. you're checking if `on` is equal to `True`, which it is not. Change that line to an assignment `on = True` and your code will work as you expect it to. However I can't work out what you're doing with `go` and the `return` line is not in a function and thus can't return to anywhere.